# Getting the "text" from a script element using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm working on a web scraper, and the site I'm scraping has a `script` element on the page that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(window).load(function($) {
                        Morris.Line({
                          element: 'mpr-graph',
                          data: [
                            {'date': '25-04-2017','y':'1.05'},
                            {'date': '25-04-2017','y':'1.50'},
                            ...
```

**What I want:**

I want to get to the `data` property of the object passed to `Morris.Line` so that I can turn the data into something usable.

I've managed to select the correct element as a Selenium WebElement using the surrounding div's id and the tag name `script`, but now I'm stuck.

Is there a way to get the text of a script element using Selenium? The `text` property is empty since it only returns the text shown on the page for a given element.

**What I've tried:**

Since I was able to get the text in the browser console by grabbing the text property of the element, I tried using `execute_script`.

```
script_text = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('avg').getElementsByTagName('script');")
```

This returns a WebElement, so we're back to square 1, but at least we know it's working so we can move on to:

```
script_text = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('avg').getElementsByTagName('script').text;")
```

I thought this might work since it works in the browser console, but Selenium returns nothing.

```
script_text = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('avg').getElementsByTagName('script').innerHTML;")
```

As above.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use an XPath to find the `SCRIPT` tag based on its contents

```
script_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[contains(.,'mpr-graph')]").text
```

If for some reason that isn't specific enough (more than one `SCRIPT` tag contains "mpr-graph") then you can adjust it to whatever text is unique among `SCRIPT` tags.

Comment: Great Solution @JeffC !